# Mobile connect - sending sms after file drops

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

So I thought sending an SMS to customers everytime the client drops a file would be easy, but I am struggling.

- File load into DE - working fine
- Import into Mobile connect - working fine

However the bit I am struggling with is how do you send a SMS message only to customers in the most recent file. The automation adds them to a pre-defined list - but then the only option I can see is to send to the whole list. I just want to send to new customers. (i.e if my file has 5 customers - it sends 5 sms only).

One way I thought of doing this is:
Step 1 - Import contacts into List 1
Step 2 - Send SMS (using list 1 as audience and list 2 as suppression)
Step 3 - Import contacts into List 2

This way when the next file arrives and is processed - everyone in the previous file will be have been added to List 2 - and as such suppressed.

I am sure there must be an easy way to do this without the use of filters and timestamps, or the method above.

Any suggestions - there must be an easier way of doing it than this.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution was an Automation that:

1 - imports customers into DE with a smssent flag = N.

2 - Records are imported into mobile connect from DE

3 - Triggered sms send with a filter of smssent = N

4 - Update De set smssent = Y